# Core Data NSPredicate With To One Relationship to Another Entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship, nspredicate

I an trying to construct an NSPredicate to search one entity (table) but also search relationships to other entities but am getting an `'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate'` error.

The main entity is Files.  The Files have a relationship to another entity called Activity. Activity has a string property: name.

However, I cannot get the following NSPredicate to work:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Files"];   
NSPredicate *predActivity = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY self.activity.name contains[cd] %@",string];
```

The Files table has a relationship named activity that shows o as the relationship.

I've also tried it without self as in:

```
NSPredicate *predActivity = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY activity.name contains[cd] %@",string];
```

What is the correct way to write this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Is the relationship from Files to Activity to-one, or to-many?  If it’s to-one, you don’t need the ANY, just “activity.name contains[cd] %@“.

Comment: It is to one. However, removing the self and ANY yielded same error. CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x7b3800077c40> , unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (activity.name CONTAINS[cd] "react") with userInfo of (null).  Is there a way to see the SQL equivalent of the nspredicate for help in debuggin??